# Procedure of largest lyapunov exponent calculation

Tags: mathematical-physics, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

I am currently learning about chaos theory and lyapunov exponents. Specifically I am looking at a double pendulum and I am trying to calculate its largest lyapunov exponent. For that I am using the method of starting with to points in phase space that are very close to eachother, performing some iterations of both, comparing the new distance between the two points, calculating the corresponding "local" lyapunov exponent, readjusting the distance between the two to the initially chosen distance without changing this vector`s direction and then repeating this process. In the end the average of all local exponents is calculated.
For a more detailed explanation of the procedure: https://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/chaos/lyapexp.htm

Strangely, this method will end up giving me values like 12.5 for chaotic initial conditions and values like 1.5 for non chaotic initial conditions. Even though there is a noticable difference this output simply is not correct. Both numbers are way to large(I read that a reasonable value for the LLE of a double pendulum is around 1.7 for chaotic parameters).
The following are my questions:

- How many iterations should be between each calculation of the "local" exponent(I am
  currently using just one)?
- For how long should I look at the system, does that even matter?
- Is the fact that the system has no attractor responsible for these very large numbers?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You seem to know very much about this topic...